# Having trouble loading MySQL database via Hibernate in Eclipse

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, hibernate

*Resolved* 
The problem lay with by JBoss standalone.xml file.  Fat fingered the database name - and then it can't find tables.  To anyone else who is seeing this error (because I found a lot of unresolved) look to your driver and database definitions.

I am trying to load a populated MySQL database through Hibernate in Eclipse.  I know I have successfully connected the database, because I can ping it through Eclipse.  However when I publish it informs me that the table is not found.  I'm not sure what I missed.

See below the persistence.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="TEST">
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/CSER-DS</jta-data-source>
    <class>org.package.Nicknames</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="db_user"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value=""/>           
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cser_db"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
     </properties>           
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

The Entity File:

```
package org.package.Nicknames;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.lang.String;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="Nicknames")
public class Nicknames implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "longName", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String longName;

    @Column(name = "shortName", nullable = false, length = 25)
    private String shortName;

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public String getName() {
        return longName;
    }
    public void setName(String longName) {
        this.longName = longName;
    }

    public String getShortName() {
        return shortName;
    }
    public void setShortName(String shortName) {
        this.shortName = shortName;
    }

    public static long getSerialversionuid() {
        return serialVersionUID;
    }     
}
```

And the error I have:

```
16:16:40,483 INFO  [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator] (MSC service thread 1-5) HHH000130: Instantiating explicit connection provider: org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider
16:16:40,674 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (MSC service thread 1-5) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
16:16:40,680 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder] (MSC service thread 1-5) HHH000423: Disabling contextual LOB creation as JDBC driver reported JDBC version [3] less than 4
16:16:40,689 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator] (MSC service thread 1-5) HHH000268: Transaction strategy: org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.CMTTransactionFactory
16:16:40,693 INFO  [org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory] (MSC service thread 1-5) HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
16:16:40,721 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.util.Version] (MSC service thread 1-5) Hibernate Validator 4.2.0.Final
16:16:40,931 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] (MSC service thread 1-5) HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
16:16:40,932 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] (MSC service thread 1-5) HHH000102: Fetching database metadata
16:16:40,936 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] (MSC service thread 1-5) HHH000396: Updating schema
16:16:40,941 INFO  [java.sql.DatabaseMetaData] (MSC service thread 1-5) HHH000262: Table not found: Nicknames
16:16:40,942 INFO  [java.sql.DatabaseMetaData] (MSC service thread 1-5) HHH000262: Table not found: Nicknames
16:16:40,947 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] (MSC service thread 1-5) HHH000388: Unsuccessful: create table Nicknames (longName varchar(50) not null unique, shortName varchar(25) not null, primary key (longName)) ENGINE=InnoDB
16:16:40,948 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] (MSC service thread 1-5) Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE TABLE NICKNAMES (LONGNAME VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE, SHORTNAME VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (LONGNAME)) ENGINE=[*]INNODB "; expected "identifier"; SQL statement:
create table Nicknames (longName varchar(50) not null unique, shortName varchar(25) not null, primary key (longName)) ENGINE=InnoDB [42001-161]
16:16:40,949 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] (MSC service thread 1-5) HHH000232: Schema update complete
16:16:40,971 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS016008: Starting weld service for deployment TEST.war
16:16:41,578 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (MSC service thread 1-3) Initializing Mojarra 2.1.7-jbossorg-1 (20120227-1401) for context '/TEST'
16:16:42,445 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS018210: Registering web context: /TEST
16:16:42,506 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018559: Deployed "TEST.war"
```

Comment: Are you sure that your table is called exactly `Nicknames`?

Comment: What happens if you discard `unique = true, nullable = false` from longName column definition (it's redundant anyway)

Comment: If I discard the redundant code there is no change to the output.  I checked the table name, and its exactly as it should be, unless Hibernate changes the database name from the MySQL table.

Answer (score 0):

Remove unique=true, nullable=false . Because it is already primary key. So need to put again.

```
@Id
@Column(name = "longName")
private String longName;
```